# Setting output path for cl.exe

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I'm using command line param Fo, command line is like this:

```
file1.c  /ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue /bigobj /FdDebug\vc100.pdb /FoDebug\ /FaDebug\
```

But some files still are produced outside of Debug folder (exe, ilk, pdb)
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are files produced by the *linker*.  You'll need to run it separately or use the /link compiler option so you can control its output.  Use the /OUT option to set the .exe and .ilk locations, the /PDB option to set the .pdb location.

Comment: I don't see `/c`, so the linker is spawned as a subprocess of `cl.exe`.

Comment: `cl.exe` will pass any command line options after [`/link`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y4fae15.aspx) to the linker, no need to run it separately.

Comment: No, not /Fd, that is a compiler option and only sets the location of the program database.  Used by the linker, later, to generate the PDB file that the debugger uses.

Answer (score 2):

Because (like [DCoder said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393315/setting-output-path-for-cl-exe#comment13403400_10393553)) `cl.exe` passes any command line options after `/link` to the linker, you can do it in one line:

```
cl.exe <all your cl arguments here> /link user32.lib <and other lib here> /libpath:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\windows\v7.0A\Lib\" /out:files\newfilename.exe
```

You can change `files\newfilename.exe` to be whatever you want. If you run from a batch file, you can do something like `files\%1.exe` and etc...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was looking for the same thing and I found everything in [cl documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/output-file-f-options?view=msvc-160). However this page was the first one in google while I was searching, so I am putting the reference here

- /FA, /Fa (Listing File)
- Specifying the Pathname
- /Fd (Name PDB File)
- /Fe (Name EXE File)
- /FI (Name Forced Include File)
- /Fm (Name Mapfile)
- /Fo (Name Object File)
- /Fp (Name .pch File)
- /FR, /Fr (Create .sbr File)
- /FU (Name Forced #using File)
- /Fx (Merge Injected Code)